# what tag should we use for struts 1 < bean:size tag in struts 2

Tags: struts2, tags, migration, javabeans, struts1

In my code, I have used bean tag lib from sturts. Now I want to migrate from 1 to struts 2. So for the below code what tag should I use.
< bean:size id="beansize" name="BeanSizeForm" property="list"/>

Answer (score 1):

In OGNL you simply access via normal method calls (or getters if there's a JavaBean-standard getter), e.g.,

```
<s:property value="%{someList.size()}" />
```

Or use OGNL's list enhancements:

```
<s:property value="%{someList.size}" />
```

You may be able to do this via normal JSP EL as well (haven't tried lately):

```
${someList.size}
```

You'll probably want to read up on what OGNL provides; it's a little slow, but quite powerful.